# How Route Table are build when custom route is defines in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

The custom routes are defined using routes.add in RegisterRoutes method on RouteConfig Class.

```
routes.Add("Default", new ABCRoute("{*url}",
                  new
                  {
                      languageCulture = "en",
                      pos = "uk",
                      area = defArea,
                      controller = "XXX",
                      action = "YYY",
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional
                  },
                 new { languageCulture = @Supportedlang , pos = @SupportedPos },
                  null, new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

The ABCRoute is a class which inherit Route class.

The ABCClass is similar to GreedyClass in the following link and shown below.
http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html

on First request to application, This constructor with parameter is called and it doesnot return anything.

How route is defined and route table are build when we call Route.Add() method as given above.

How route table has all possible combination, since route defied is dynamic not static.

```
   1:  using System.Collections.Generic;
   2:  using System.Globalization;
   3:  using System.Linq;
   4:  using System.Text;
   5:  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   6:   
   7:  namespace System.Web.Routing
   8:  {
   9:      /// <summary>
  10:      /// This route is used for cases where we want greedy route segments anywhere in the route URL definition
  11:      /// </summary>
  12:      public class GreedyRoute : Route
  13:      {
  14:          #region Properties
  15:   
  16:          /// <summary>Gets the URL pattern for the route.</summary>
  17:          public new string Url { get; private set; }
  18:   
  19:          private LinkedList<GreedyRouteSegment> urlSegments = new LinkedList<GreedyRouteSegment>();
  20:   
  21:          private bool hasGreedySegment = false;
  22:   
  23:          /// <summary>Gets minimum number of segments that this route requires.</summary>
  24:          public int MinRequiredSegments { get; private set; }
  25:   
  26:          #endregion
  27:   
  28:          #region Constructors
  29:   
  30:          /// <summary>
  31:          /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GreedyRoute"/> class, using the specified URL pattern and handler class.
  32:          /// </summary>
  33:          /// <param name="url">The URL pattern for the route.</param>
  34:          /// <param name="routeHandler">The object that processes requests for the route.</param>
  35:          public GreedyRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
  36:              : this(url, null, null, null, routeHandler)
  37:          {
  38:          }
  39:   
  40:          /// <summary>
  41:          /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GreedyRoute"/> class, using the specified URL pattern, handler class, and default parameter values.
  42:          /// </summary>
  43:          /// <param name="url">The URL pattern for the route.</param>
  44:          /// <param name="defaults">The values to use if the URL does not contain all the parameters.</param>
  45:          /// <param name="routeHandler">The object that processes requests for the route.</param>
  46:          public GreedyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
  47:              : this(url, defaults, null, null, routeHandler)
  48:          {
  49:          }
  50:   
  51:          /// <summary>
  52:          /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GreedyRoute"/> class, using the specified URL pattern, handler class, default parameter values, and constraints.
  53:          /// </summary>
  54:          /// <param name="url">The URL pattern for the route.</param>
  55:          /// <param name="defaults">The values to use if the URL does not contain all the parameters.</param>
  56:          /// <param name="constraints">A regular expression that specifies valid values for a URL parameter.</param>
  57:          /// <param name="routeHandler">The object that processes requests for the route.</param>
  58:          public GreedyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
  59:              : this(url, defaults, constraints, null, routeHandler)
  60:          {
  61:          }
  62:   
  63:          /// <summary>
  64:          /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GreedyRoute"/> class, using the specified URL pattern, handler class, default parameter values, constraints, and custom values.
  65:          /// </summary>
  66:          /// <param name="url">The URL pattern for the route.</param>
  67:          /// <param name="defaults">The values to use if the URL does not contain all the parameters.</param>
  68:          /// <param name="constraints">A regular expression that specifies valid values for a URL parameter.</param>
  69:          /// <param name="dataTokens">Custom values that are passed to the route handler, but which are not used to determine whether the route matches a specific URL pattern. The route handler might need these values to process the request.</param>
  70:          /// <param name="routeHandler">The object that processes requests for the route.</param>
  71:          public GreedyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
  72:              : base(url.Replace("*", ""), defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler)
  73:          {
  74:              this.Defaults = defaults ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
  75:              this.Constraints = constraints;
  76:              this.DataTokens = dataTokens;
  77:              this.RouteHandler = routeHandler;
  78:              this.Url = url;
  79:              this.MinRequiredSegments = 0;
  80:   
  81:              // URL must be defined
  82:              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
  83:              {
  84:                  throw new ArgumentException("Route URL must be defined.", "url");
  85:              }
  86:   
  87:              // correct URL definition can have AT MOST ONE greedy segment
  88:              if (url.Split('*').Length > 2)
  89:              {
  90:                  throw new ArgumentException("Route URL can have at most one greedy segment, but not more.", "url");
  91:              }
  92:   
  93:              Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(?<isToken>{)?(?(isToken)(?<isGreedy>\*?))(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(?(isToken)})$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
  94:              foreach (string segment in url.Split('/'))
  95:              {
  96:                  // segment must not be empty
  97:                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(segment))
  98:                  {
  99:                      throw new ArgumentException("Route URL is invalid. Sequence \"//\" is not allowed.", "url");
 100:                  }
 101:   
 102:                  if (rx.IsMatch(segment))
 103:                  {
 104:                      Match m = rx.Match(segment);
 105:                      GreedyRouteSegment s = new GreedyRouteSegment {
 106:                          IsToken = m.Groups["isToken"].Value.Length.Equals(1),
 107:                          IsGreedy = m.Groups["isGreedy"].Value.Length.Equals(1),
 108:                          Name = m.Groups["name"].Value
 109:                      };
 110:                      this.urlSegments.AddLast(s);
 111:                      this.hasGreedySegment |= s.IsGreedy;
 112:   
 113:                      continue;
 114:                  }
 115:                  throw new ArgumentException("Route URL is invalid.", "url");
 116:              }
 117:   
 118:              // get minimum required segments for this route
 119:              LinkedListNode<GreedyRouteSegment> seg = this.urlSegments.Last;
 120:              int sIndex = this.urlSegments.Count;
 121:              while (seg != null && this.MinRequiredSegments.Equals(0))
 122:              {
 123:                  if (!seg.Value.IsToken || !this.Defaults.ContainsKey(seg.Value.Name))
 124:                  {
 125:                      this.MinRequiredSegments = Math.Max(this.MinRequiredSegments, sIndex);
 126:                  }
 127:                  sIndex--;
 128:                  seg = seg.Previous;
 129:              }
 130:   
 131:              // check that segments after greedy segment don't define a default
 132:              if (this.hasGreedySegment)
 133:              {
 134:                  LinkedListNode<GreedyRouteSegment> s = this.urlSegments.Last;
 135:                  while (s != null && !s.Value.IsGreedy)
 136:                  {
 137:                      if (s.Value.IsToken && this.Defaults.ContainsKey(s.Value.Name))
 138:                      {
 139:                          throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Defaults for route segment \"{0}\" is not allowed, because it's specified after greedy catch-all segment.", s.Value.Name), "defaults");
 140:                      }
 141:                      s = s.Previous;
 142:                  }
 143:              }
 144:          }
 145:   
 146:          #endregion
 147:   
 148:          #region GetRouteData
 149:          /// <summary>
 150:          /// Returns information about the requested route.
 151:          /// </summary>
 152:          /// <param name="httpContext">An object that encapsulates information about the HTTP request.</param>
 153:          /// <returns>
 154:          /// An object that contains the values from the route definition.
 155:          /// </returns>
 156:          public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
 157:          {
 158:              string virtualPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) + (httpContext.Request.PathInfo ?? string.Empty);
 159:   
 160:              RouteValueDictionary values = this.ParseRoute(virtualPath);
 161:              if (values == null)
 162:              {
 163:                  return null;
 164:              }
 165:   
 166:              RouteData result = new RouteData(this, this.RouteHandler);
 167:              if (!this.ProcessConstraints(httpContext, values, RouteDirection.IncomingRequest))
 168:              {
 169:                  return null;
 170:              }
 171:   
 172:              // everything's fine, fill route data
 173:              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> value in values)
 174:              {
 175:                  result.Values.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
 176:              }
 177:              if (this.DataTokens != null)
 178:              {
 179:                  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> token in this.DataTokens)
 180:                  {
 181:                      result.DataTokens.Add(token.Key, token.Value);
 182:                  }
 183:              }
 184:              return result;
 185:          }
 186:          #endregion
 187:   
 188:          #region GetVirtualPath
 189:          /// <summary>
 190:          /// Returns information about the URL that is associated with the route.
 191:          /// </summary>
 192:          /// <param name="requestContext">An object that encapsulates information about the requested route.</param>
 193:          /// <param name="values">An object that contains the parameters for a route.</param>
 194:          /// <returns>
 195:          /// An object that contains information about the URL that is associated with the route.
 196:          /// </returns>
 197:          public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
 198:          {
 199:              RouteUrl url = this.Bind(requestContext.RouteData.Values, values);
 200:              if (url == null)
 201:              {
 202:                  return null;
 203:              }
 204:              if (!this.ProcessConstraints(requestContext.HttpContext, url.Values, RouteDirection.UrlGeneration))
 205:              {
 206:                  return null;
 207:              }
 208:   
 209:              VirtualPathData data = new VirtualPathData(this, url.Url);
 210:              if (this.DataTokens != null)
 211:              {
 212:                  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in this.DataTokens)
 213:                  {
 214:                      data.DataTokens[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
 215:                  }
 216:              }
 217:              return data;
 218:          }
 219:          #endregion
 220:   
 221:          #region Private methods
 222:   
 223:          #region ProcessConstraints
 224:          /// <summary>
 225:          /// Processes constraints.
 226:          /// </summary>
 227:          /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context.</param>
 228:          /// <param name="values">Route values.</param>
 229:          /// <param name="direction">Route direction.</param>
 230:          /// <returns><c>true</c> if constraints are satisfied; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
 231:          private bool ProcessConstraints(HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection direction)
 232:          {
 233:              if (this.Constraints != null)
 234:              {
 235:                  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> constraint in this.Constraints)
 236:                  {
 237:                      if (!this.ProcessConstraint(httpContext, constraint.Value, constraint.Key, values, direction))
 238:                      {
 239:                          return false;
 240:                      }
 241:                  }
 242:              }
 243:              return true;
 244:          }
 245:          #endregion
 246:   
 247:          #region ParseRoute
 248:          /// <summary>
 249:          /// Parses the route into segment data as defined by this route.
 250:          /// </summary>
 251:          /// <param name="virtualPath">Virtual path.</param>
 252:          /// <returns>Returns <see cref="System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary"/> dictionary of route values.</returns>
 253:          private RouteValueDictionary ParseRoute(string virtualPath)
 254:          {
 255:              Stack<string> parts = new Stack<string>(
 256:                  virtualPath
 257:                  .Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 258:                  .Reverse() // we have to reverse it because parsing starts at the beginning not the end.
 259:              );
 260:   
 261:              // number of request route parts must match route URL definition
 262:              if (parts.Count < this.MinRequiredSegments)
 263:              {
 264:                  return null;
 265:              }
 266:   
 267:              RouteValueDictionary result = new RouteValueDictionary();
 268:   
 269:              // start parsing from the beginning
 270:              bool finished = false;
 271:              LinkedListNode<GreedyRouteSegment> currentSegment = this.urlSegments.First;
 272:              while (!finished && !currentSegment.Value.IsGreedy)
 273:              {
 274:                  object p = parts.Count > 0 ? parts.Pop() : null;
 275:                  if (currentSegment.Value.IsToken)
 276:                  {
 277:                      p = p ?? this.Defaults[currentSegment.Value.Name];
 278:                      result.Add(currentSegment.Value.Name, p);
 279:                  }
 280:                  else
 281:                  {
 282:                      if (!currentSegment.Value.Name.Equals(p))
 283:                      {
 284:                          return null;
 285:                      }
 286:                  }
 287:                  currentSegment = currentSegment.Next;
 288:                  finished = currentSegment == null;
 289:              }
 290:   
 291:              // continue from the end if needed
 292:              parts = new Stack<string>(parts); // this will reverse stack elements
 293:              currentSegment = this.urlSegments.Last;
 294:              while (!finished && !currentSegment.Value.IsGreedy)
 295:              {
 296:                  object p = parts.Count > 0 ? parts.Pop() : null;
 297:                  if (currentSegment.Value.IsToken)
 298:                  {
 299:                      p = p ?? this.Defaults[currentSegment.Value.Name];
 300:                      result.Add(currentSegment.Value.Name, p);
 301:                  }
 302:                  else
 303:                  {
 304:                      if (!currentSegment.Value.Name.Equals(p))
 305:                      {
 306:                          return null;
 307:                      }
 308:                  }
 309:                  currentSegment = currentSegment.Previous;
 310:                  finished = currentSegment == null;
 311:              }
 312:   
 313:              // fill in the greedy catch-all segment
 314:              if (!finished)
 315:              {
 316:                  object remaining = string.Join("/", parts.Reverse().ToArray()) ?? this.Defaults[currentSegment.Value.Name];
 317:                  result.Add(currentSegment.Value.Name, remaining);
 318:              }
 319:   
 320:              // add remaining default values
 321:              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> def in this.Defaults)
 322:              {
 323:                  if (!result.ContainsKey(def.Key))
 324:                  {
 325:                      result.Add(def.Key, def.Value);
 326:                  }
 327:              }
 328:   
 329:              return result;
 330:          }
 331:          #endregion
 332:   
 333:          #region Bind
 334:          /// <summary>
 335:          /// Binds the specified current values and values into a URL.
 336:          /// </summary>
 337:          /// <param name="currentValues">Current route data values.</param>
 338:          /// <param name="values">Additional route values that can be used to generate the URL.</param>
 339:          /// <returns>Returns a URL route string.</returns>
 340:          private RouteUrl Bind(RouteValueDictionary currentValues, RouteValueDictionary values)
 341:          {
 342:              currentValues = currentValues ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
 343:              values = values ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
 344:   
 345:              HashSet<string> required = new HashSet<string>(this.urlSegments.Where(seg => seg.IsToken).ToList().ConvertAll(seg => seg.Name), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 346:              RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
 347:   
 348:              object dataValue = null;
 349:              foreach (string token in new List<string>(required))
 350:              {
 351:                  dataValue = values[token] ?? currentValues[token] ?? this.Defaults[token];
 352:                  if (this.IsUsable(dataValue))
 353:                  {
 354:                      string val = dataValue as string;
 355:                      if (val != null)
 356:                      {
 357:                          val = val.StartsWith("/") ? val.Substring(1) : val;
 358:                          val = val.EndsWith("/") ? val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1) : val;
 359:                      }
 360:                      routeValues.Add(token, val ?? dataValue);
 361:                      required.Remove(token);
 362:                  }
 363:              }
 364:   
 365:              // this route data is not related to this route
 366:              if (required.Count > 0)
 367:              {
 368:                  return null;
 369:              }
 370:   
 371:              // add all remaining values
 372:              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair1 in values)
 373:              {
 374:                  if (this.IsUsable(pair1.Value) && !routeValues.ContainsKey(pair1.Key))
 375:                  {
 376:                      routeValues.Add(pair1.Key, pair1.Value);
 377:                  }
 378:              }
 379:   
 380:              // add remaining defaults
 381:              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair2 in this.Defaults)
 382:              {
 383:                  if (this.IsUsable(pair2.Value) && !routeValues.ContainsKey(pair2.Key))
 384:                  {
 385:                      routeValues.Add(pair2.Key, pair2.Value);
 386:                  }
 387:              }
 388:   
 389:              // check that non-segment defaults are the same as those provided
 390:              RouteValueDictionary nonRouteDefaults = new RouteValueDictionary(this.Defaults);
 391:              foreach (GreedyRouteSegment seg in this.urlSegments.Where(ss => ss.IsToken))
 392:              {
 393:                  nonRouteDefaults.Remove(seg.Name);
 394:              }
 395:              foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair3 in nonRouteDefaults)
 396:              {
 397:                  if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(pair3.Key) || !this.RoutePartsEqual(pair3.Value, routeValues[pair3.Key]))
 398:                  {
 399:                      // route data is not related to this route
 400:                      return null;
 401:                  }
 402:              }
 403:   
 404:              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 405:              RouteValueDictionary valuesToUse = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
 406:              bool mustAdd = this.hasGreedySegment;
 407:   
 408:              // build URL string
 409:              LinkedListNode<GreedyRouteSegment> s = this.urlSegments.Last;
 410:              object segmentValue = null;
 411:              while (s != null)
 412:              {
 413:                  if (s.Value.IsToken)
 414:                  {
 415:                      segmentValue = valuesToUse[s.Value.Name];
 416:                      mustAdd = mustAdd || !this.RoutePartsEqual(segmentValue, this.Defaults[s.Value.Name]);
 417:                      valuesToUse.Remove(s.Value.Name);
 418:                  }
 419:                  else
 420:                  {
 421:                      segmentValue = s.Value.Name;
 422:                      mustAdd = true;
 423:                  }
 424:   
 425:                  if (mustAdd)
 426:                  {
 427:                      sb.Insert(0, sb.Length > 0 ? "/" : string.Empty);
 428:                      sb.Insert(0, Uri.EscapeUriString(Convert.ToString(segmentValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
 429:                  }
 430:   
 431:                  s = s.Previous;
 432:              }
 433:   
 434:              // add remaining values
 435:              if (valuesToUse.Count > 0)
 436:              {
 437:                  bool first = true;
 438:                  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair3 in valuesToUse)
 439:                  {
 440:                      // only add when different from defaults
 441:                      if (!this.RoutePartsEqual(pair3.Value, this.Defaults[pair3.Key]))
 442:                      {
 443:                          sb.Append(first ? "?" : "&");
 444:                          sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(pair3.Key));
 445:                          sb.Append("=");
 446:                          sb.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(pair3.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
 447:                          first = false;
 448:                      }
 449:                  }
 450:              }
 451:   
 452:              return new RouteUrl {
 453:                  Url = sb.ToString(),
 454:                  Values = routeValues
 455:              };
 456:          }
 457:          #endregion
 458:   
 459:          #region IsUsable
 460:          /// <summary>
 461:          /// Determines whether an object actually is instantiated or has a value.
 462:          /// </summary>
 463:          /// <param name="value">Object value to check.</param>
 464:          /// <returns>
 465:          ///     <c>true</c> if an object is instantiated or has a value; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
 466:          /// </returns>
 467:          private bool IsUsable(object value)
 468:          {
 469:              string val = value as string;
 470:              if (val != null)
 471:              {
 472:                  return val.Length > 0;
 473:              }
 474:              return value != null;
 475:          }
 476:          #endregion
 477:   
 478:          #region RoutePartsEqual
 479:          /// <summary>
 480:          /// Checks if two route parts are equal
 481:          /// </summary>
 482:          /// <param name="firstValue">The first value.</param>
 483:          /// <param name="secondValue">The second value.</param>
 484:          /// <returns><c>true</c> if both values are equal; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
 485:          private bool RoutePartsEqual(object firstValue, object secondValue)
 486:          {
 487:              string sFirst = firstValue as string;
 488:              string sSecond = secondValue as string;
 489:              if ((sFirst != null) && (sSecond != null))
 490:              {
 491:                  return string.Equals(sFirst, sSecond, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 492:              }
 493:              if ((firstValue != null) && (secondValue != null))
 494:              {
 495:                  return firstValue.Equals(secondValue);
 496:              }
 497:              return (firstValue == secondValue);
 498:          }
 499:          #endregion
 500:   
 501:          #endregion
 502:      }
 503:  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How route table has all possible combination, since route defied is dynamic not static.

Routes are defined in the *static* `RouteTable.Routes` table. Therefore, they are only instantiated at application initialization. The only thing that you can do in the constructor is *save values and services* that can be used for evaluation at runtime.

At runtime the constructor is *never* run. Routes are evaluated in the route table from the first route to the last. However, when a matching route is found, routing will use that route and not continue any further. In other words, the first match wins.

Consider this example:

```
routes.Add(new ABCRoute());
routes.Add(new XYZRoute());
```

MVC will *always* attempt to match the `ABCRoute` first and, if `ABCRoute` failed to match, the `XYZRoute` next.

A route is considered to be a match if it returns a **non null** value. So, the logic in your route must *always* return `null` if it determines that it should not handle the request. This will make the routing framework test the next route that is registered for a match.

If a route matches, it should return the *route values* that tell MVC which controller and action to lookup (along with any parameters).

> **NOTE:** You cannot assume *anything* about what the `ABCRoute` does based on the fact that it inherits `GreedyRoute`, since `ABCRoute` can completely redefine its superclass behavior.